# How to convert "Matrix" to "Data Frame" in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I built feature matrix by using "Vectorizer" with below coding

```
matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(list)
```

and I apply under Code to convert matrix to Data Frame.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
```

But I got an error :

```
 DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: hi, what is the type of your matrix?
data type must be ndarray (structured or homogeneous), Iterable, dict, or DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your matrix which is certainly a sparse matrix, into a dense matrix.

```
matrix = matrix.todense()
```